# Align multiple togglebuttons?

Tags: android, layout, togglebutton

I need to have 7 toggle buttons to represent the days of the week, like you would see on the default android alarm app.

Is there a way to line up the 7 buttons so they resize and fit on one line horizontally?

Scratching my head on this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a LinearLayout with orientation=horizontal and put ToggleButtons with width=0dp and weight=1

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```